# Open JPanel on JFrame from Button on another panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to close a `JPanel` that's on top of my `JFrame`.

Now I want to close this panel by clicking a button that's on top of this panel and open another panel on the same frame.

All my panels and my frame is in a separated class.

Here is my idea:

### `JFrame` Class

```
public MainFrame() throws IOException {
        InitializeStartScreen();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setIconImage(FrameTopIcon.getImage());
        this.setTitle("test");
        this.setVisible(true);
}

private void InitializeStartScreen() {
    StartPanel startPNL = new StartPanel();
    this.add(startPNL);
   // pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    try {
        new MainFrame();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw  e;
    }
}
```

### `JPanel` Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StartPanel extends JPanel {
private LabelButtonCategory Button1         = new LabelButtonCategory("test");

public StartPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    InitializeLabelButtons();       

    this.setBackground(backgroundColor);
    this.add(gridPanel);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

    private void InitializeLabelButtons() {
         button1Panel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
         ImageIcon iconBtn1 = new ImageIcon("./src/images/CreateBill.png");
         Button1.setIcon(iconBtn1);
         Button1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            Button1MouseClicked(evt);
         }
         public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            Button1MouseEntered(evt);
         }
         public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            Button1MouseExited(evt);
         }
         });
        button1Panel.add(Button1);
        gridPanel.add(button1Panel);

   private void Button1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      // CLOSE THIS PANEL AND OPEN ANOTHER PANEL ON FRAME
   }
```

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) The constructor of `MainFrame` does not throw an `IOException`. ..

Comment: .. 5) a `JButton` is usually better suited to an `ActionListener` rather than a mouse listener. 6) A `JButton` has inbuilt capacity to change icons on mouse entered or exit. 7) There is no need or good point here to extending `JPanel` or `JFrame`.

Comment: thx for some food for thought. I redesigned my code a little bit to common Java nomenclature and my class not logner extends jpanel. I will have a look at CardLayout now.